# In linux how to find tomcat server is running in multple port in different systems without mentioning portnumber

Tags: linux, apache, unix, tomcat

read INPUT_STRING
  case $INPUT_STRING in

```
stop)

    check=`netstat -na | grep 8080 | awk '{print $6}'|head -1`
    if [ "$check" = "TIME_WAIT" ]; then
        echo "DEFAULT TOMCAT PORT IS LISTENING, SO ITS stopped already..."
    else 
        sh /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.39/bin/shutdown.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
    echo "Tomcat server is stopped....."

    fi
```

Here My code is finding tomcat server running on 8080 port only so that it is easily find whether the tomcat is running or not. But What actually i need is to stop/start the tomcat server if it is running or stoped status in some other ports.....

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of pids on which tomcat is running, and check each one:

```
declare -a list
list=( `ps -AChS | grep '[t]omcat' | awk '{ print $1 }'`)  
for i in ${list[*]} ; 
    do netstat -vlp tcp | awk '{ print $6, $9 }' | grep "$i" ; 
done
unset "$list"
```

I'm creating an array of tomcat pids here, then using grep to find the network status of each pid. Once I'm done with the loop, I clear out the array. Note: netstat has different implementations on various operating systems, in my case I am using verbose which shows the pid of process and filtering by tcp.

Use the catalina.sh to either start or stop the service, e.g. `catalina.sh stop`

Comment: I know this command already, If port changes of tomcat server how to identify it ....

Comment: why do you care if the port changes, when all you want to do is stop the service? please explain.

Comment: In my code , I fetch the status of the tomcat server by passing netstat -na | grep 8080 | awk '{print $6}'|head -1 this command . This command gives status of Listen if the tomcat server is running otherwise it returns TIME_WAIT  from that i identify the server is started /stopped status .. Based on the status I need to restart the server or stop the server..

Answer (score 0):

```
# This script is works based on tomcat server is running or stopped status. if it is stopped I need to restart it by giving option as start otherwise stop based on the requirement....

#!/bin/sh
echo "Choose Your Option---- status or stop.."
echo 
echo "Enter Your Option ..."
path=`whereis -l tomcat | grep tomcat | sed 's/bin: //' |head -1`
echo $path
echo "Enter Your Option ..."
while :
do
  read INPUT_STRING
  case $INPUT_STRING in

    stop)

        check=` ps -aef |grep java| grep tomcat |awk '{print $2}'`
        if [ -z "$check" ]; then
            echo "Tomcat server is stopped already..."
        else 
            sh $path/shutdown.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
        echo "The Tomcat server is stopped successfully..."
        fi
        exit;
        ;;

    start)
        check=`ps -aef |grep java| grep tomcat |awk '{print $2}'`
        if [ ! -z ${check} ]; then
            echo "Tomcat server is already running successfully..."
        else 
            sh $path/startup.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
        echo "Tomcat server is started....."
            fi
         exit;
        ;;
    status)
        check=`ps -aef |grep java| grep tomcat |awk '{print $2}'`
        if [ ! -z ${check} ]; then
            echo "Tomcat server is already running..."
        else 
            echo "Tomcat server is stopped...."
            fi
         exit;
        ;;
  esac
done
```

Comment: This script takes where the tomcat server installation path in our server in which it starts by giving  our input as start/stop...specifically what actually i done is ps -aef |grep java| grep tomcat |awk '{print $2}' this command gives status of the tomcat is running or not if it is running we get some pid value based on which we can able to check that if condition we start the tomcat server...